# Put returns into quantiles for many time series

Tags: r, xts, quantile

I have a xts object of monthly returns (one column is a time series for one instrument). I want to know the quantile for each return, each month.
I have my own set of instruments prices from a local database but I can reproduce with `getSymbols`.

I used `quantile` on stock returns to get the boundaries of my quantile. Then I tried to use `cut` to divide my returns into quantile but I am stuck there.

Ideally I should have a time series of monthly quantile for each instrument.

```
require(quantmod)
stocks <- c("GOOG","MSFT","AAPL","T","F","FB","GE","WMT","BA","BAC")
dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(stocks, env=dataEnv)
stocks.prices <- do.call(merge, lapply(stocks,
  function(x) Cl(to.monthly(dataEnv[[x]], name=x))))

stocks.returns <- ROC(stocks.prices, n=1, type="discrete", na.pad=TRUE)
stocks.quantile <- t(apply(stocks.returns, 1, FUN=quantile, probs=seq(0,1,by=0.20), na.rm=TRUE))
stocks.cut <- t(apply(stocks.returns, 1, FUN=cut, breaks=stocks.quantile, include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you want the quantiles calculated for each stock for each month. If so, what dimension are you calculating the quantile over? If time, then you can't have ts quantiles for each stock on each date (ie, the quantiles are conditioned on the date range in the data frame).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function GetQuantile which does the work (but maybe not in an elegant way).

```
GetQuantile<-function(x,q,n){
  # Extract the nth quantile from a time series
  #
  # args:
  #   x = xts object
  #   q = quantile of xts object
  #   n = nthe quantile to extract
  #
  # Returns:
  #   Returns an xts object of quantiles

  # TRUE / FALSE depending on the quantile we are looking for
  if(n==1) # first quantile
    test<-xts((coredata(x[,])<c(coredata(q[,2]))),order.by = index(x))
  else if (n== dim(q)[2]-1) # last quantile
    test<-xts((coredata(x[,])>=c(coredata(q[,n]))),order.by = index(x))
  else # else
    test<-xts(  (coredata(monthly.returns[,])>=c(coredata(q[,n]))) &
                (coredata(monthly.returns[,])<c(coredata(q[,(n+1)])))  ,order.by = index(x))
  # replace NA by FALSE
  test[is.na(test)]<-FALSE
  # we only keep returns for which we need the quantile
  x[test==FALSE]<-NA
  return(x)
}
```

with this function I can have an xts with all the monthly returns of the quantile I want and NA everywhere else. With this xts I can do some stuff like computing the mean for each quantile ect..

```
monthly.returns.stock.Q1<-GetQuantile(stocks.returns,stocks.quantile,1)
rowMeans(monthly.returns.stock.Q1,na.rm = TRUE)
```