# Making subsets by means of quantiles

Tags: r, subset, quantile

I  made `quantiles` of equal size with the `cut2` function, now I want to make 4 different subsets, by means of the 4 quantiles.

The first and fourth quantile I can make with the subset function:

```
quantile1 <- subset (trial, NAG <22.1)

quantile4 <- subset(trial, NAG >=61.6)
```

But if I try to make subsets of the second and third quantile, it doesn’t quite work and I don’t understand why. This is what I’ve tried:

```
quantile2<- subset(trial, NAG >=22.1 | NAG<36.8)

quantile3<-subset(trial, NAG >=36.8 | NAG <61.6)
```

If I use this function, R makes a subset, but the subset consists of the total number of observations, which can’t be right. Anyone an idea about what's wrong with the syntax is or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be quantile3<-subset(trial, NAG >=36.8 & NAG <61.6)

Comment: You are absolutely right! It works now. Sometimes it can be so easy.. ;)

Comment: Check out [Venn-Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem a while ago ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137554/put-returns-into-quantiles-for-many-time-series/34229648#34229648)). I made a GetQuantile function which could be helpful to you:

```
GetQuantile<-function(x,q,n){
  # Extract the nth quantile from a time series
  #
  # args:
  #   x = xts object
  #   q = quantile of xts object
  #   n = nthe quantile to extract
  #
  # Returns:
  #   Returns an xts object of quantiles

  # TRUE / FALSE depending on the quantile we are looking for
  if(n==1) # first quantile
    test<-xts((coredata(x[,])<c(coredata(q[,2]))),order.by = index(x))
  else if (n== dim(q)[2]-1) # last quantile
    test<-xts((coredata(x[,])>=c(coredata(q[,n]))),order.by = index(x))
  else # else
    test<-xts(  (coredata(monthly.returns[,])>=c(coredata(q[,n]))) &
                (coredata(monthly.returns[,])<c(coredata(q[,(n+1)])))  ,order.by = index(x))
  # replace NA by FALSE
  test[is.na(test)]<-FALSE
  # we only keep returns for which we need the quantile
  x[test==FALSE]<-NA
  return(x)
}
```

with this function I can have an xts with all the monthly returns of the quantile I want and NA everywhere else. With this xts I can do some stuff like computing the mean for each quantile ect..

```
monthly.returns.stock.Q1<-GetQuantile(stocks.returns,stocks.quantile,1)
rowMeans(monthly.returns.stock.Q1,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used this:

```
df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$var) 
# makes cumulative sum of variable; my data were in shares, so they added up 
# to 100

df$quantile <- cut(df$cumsum, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, NA), names=TRUE) 
# cuts the cumulative sum at desired percentile
```

For variables that do not come in shares, I used the info from the summary, where R gives you quantiles and then cut the data according to those values.

Question: Are your quantiles equal? I mean, do they all contain exactly 25% of observations? Because mine were lumpy... ie some were 22%, some 28% etc. Just curious how you may have worked around that.

Comment: You can use the 'cut2' function {Hmisc}, instead of 'cut' function. 'cut2' divides the group in categories of equal size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!